# Наследование в Django models - получить поля дочерней модели

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-orm

Имеется родительская модель `CommunicationMethod`:

```py
class CommunicationMethod(models.Model):
    pass
```

Также имеется модель `Provider`, но её упустим.

От `CommunicationMethod` наследуются модели `Email` и `Letter` с одинаковым набором полей:

```py
class Email(CommunicationMethod):
    provider = models.ForeignKey(
        to=Provider, 
        related_name="emails", # !!!
        ...
    )

class Letter(CommunicationMethod):
    provider = models.ForeignKey(
        to=Provider, 
        related_name="letters", # !!!
        ...
    )
```

**В чём заключается проблема:**

Нам нужна форма для обновления поля "provider":

```py
class CommunicationMethodForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = CommunicationMethod
        fields = ["provider"] # интерпритатор будет ругаться уже на этом шаге, т.к. поля "provider" нет в модели CommunicationMethod
```

и `UpdateView` для тех же целей:

```
from django.views.generic import UpdateView

class CommunicationMethodUpdateView(UpdateView):
    form_class = CommunicationMethodForm

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        com_method = CommunicationMethod.get(id=N)
        # Тут всё аналогично, у "com_method" нет никакого аттрибута "provider"
        print("Current CommunicationMethod is {}".format(com_method.provider))
        return com_method
```

Как можно получить поля дочерней модели из объекта родительской, и (если обладаете такой информацией) как их можно использовать в формах, без необходимости создавать дочерние формы `CommunicationMethodForm` с `Meta.model = Email # или Letter`?

Comment: Ну разве что вы создадите в форме поле provider вручную, а так же переопределите метод save и в нем логику сохранения в зависимости от модели.

Comment: И ещё по идее вам нужно какое-то поле, которое будет опреднлять, какую именно модель вы хотите сохранить. Либо если тип модели будет зависеть от url, то переопределить метод get/post у updateview, чтобы передать в форму тип модели